What is the posibility for Str::random to create same string upon each app isntance in multi-server webapp?
I am making this model in my laravel Application.

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ApiKeys extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    const TABLE = 'api_keys';
    protected $table = self::TABLE;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->identifier = Str::random(16);
        });
    }
}


And upon Identifier I want to ensure that contains a unique random string:

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('api_keys', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('identifier')->unique('unique_identifier');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_keys');
    }
};


But my application runs in multiple instances behind load balancer:

Would this cause not unique random strings be generated, in other words could Str::random(16) (and the underlying function openssl_random_bytes) generate non unique string if both executed from multiple instances?
In order to avoid this usually I prepend the hostname:
  $model->identifier = gethostname()."_".Str::random(16);

But this makes the identifier look ugly or even expose some infrastructure information. How I could avoid this?

I would use a do while loop before creating the new entry to ensure the identifier doesn't exist. If so, just create a new identifier. You can't rely on random strings. Laravel provides nice methods in order to write the test corresponding.

An alternative is using uuid, prepend the hostname and base64 it or prepend an autoincrement id using db hooks.

This looks like a job for UUIDs. A UUID will give you a unique value every time and Eloquent has support for creating and using UUIDs as the model's primary key.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

"Behind a load balancer" should not be a problem here, especially as you have an index set on the database

Does your table really need two unique identifiers for each row (id and identifier)? That sounds like it's breaking 3rd normal form. The id column is assigned by database so you don't have to worry about generating unique value in your code. If you don't want to show integer ID in url to users, you can use it to calculate some identifier for example using encryption. If using auto incremented integer is not good enough you should probably remove id column and make identifier primary key with UUID values as suggested by Jon White.
